# При запуске телеграм бота ошибка - Error getting updates

Tags: java, telegram-bot

При запуске телеграм бота выходит эта ошибка

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error getting updates
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.updates.GetUpdates.deserializeResponse(GetUpdates.java:118) ~[telegrambots-meta-4.9.1.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$ReaderThread.getUpdatesFromServer(DefaultBotSession.java:264) ~[telegrambots-4.9.1.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$ReaderThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:195) ~[telegrambots-4.9.1.jar:na]
```

Инициализация бота

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class TelegramBotApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TelegramBotApplication.class, args);
}

@PostConstruct
public void initBots() {
    ApiContextInitializer.init();
    TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
    BotService botService = new BotService();
        try {
            botsApi.registerBot(botService);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема, погуглив, наткнулся на ответ, что это, возможно, из-за того, что создается вторая копия уже созданного бота.
Тут это обсуждалось: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/issues/508
Но у себя я так и не смог убрать эту ошибку, при этом всё функционирует хорошо, просто каждые три секунды эта ошибка выводится в консоль.

Comment: @SanzharSarsekov, покажите код, в котором отправляете сообщение (Не забудьте удалить токен перед публикацией).